# Azure Table Storage Explorer Query

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I would like to look at the data collected recently.
I've written some query statements, but they were shown in the order of the first data collected.

I do not know how to write a query to see the data in the order in which it was recently collected.
Please let me know if you have any related tips.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can click on `Timestamp` column and view the data in ascending or descending order as there is no support for `Order by` queries in Azure Storage Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

> I do not know how to write a query to see the data in the order in which it was recently collected.

Based on the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Query-Operators-Supported-for-the-Table-Service), the order by query is not support by Azure Table Service currently. The query result is default order by PartitionKey and  RowKey.